# Trying to understand spark streaming flow

Tags: apache-spark

I have this piece of code:

```
val lines: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(String, String)] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
    lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      val df = cassandraSQLContext.read.json(rdd.map(x => x._2))
      sparkStreamingService.run(df)
    }
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The way I understand it is, foreachRDD is happening at the driver level? So basically all that block of code:

```
lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val df = cassandraSQLContext.read.json(rdd.map(x => x._2))
  sparkStreamingService.run(df)
}
```

is happening at the driver level? The sparkStreamingService.run(df) method basically does some transformations on the current dataframe to yield a new dataframe and then calls another method (on another jar) which stores the dataframe to cassandra.
So if this is happening all at the driver level, we are not utilizing the spark executors and how can I make it so that the executors are being used in parallel to process each partition of the RDD in parallel

My spark streaming service run method:

```
    var metadataDataframe = df.select("customer", "tableName", "messageContent", "initialLoadRunning").collect()
 metadataDataframe.foreach(rowD => {
      metaData = populateMetaDataService.populateSiteMetaData(rowD)
      val headers = (rowD.getString(2).split(recordDelimiter)(0))

      val fields = headers.split("\u0001").map(
        fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
      val schema = StructType(fields)

      val listOfRawData = rowD.getString(2).indexOf(recordDelimiter)
      val dataWithoutHeaders = rowD.getString(2).substring(listOfRawData + 1)

      val rawData = sparkContext.parallelize(dataWithoutHeaders.split(recordDelimiter))
//      val rawData = dataWithoutHeaders.split(recordDelimiter)
      val rowRDD = rawData
        .map(_.split("\u0001"))
        .map(attributes => Row(attributes: _*))

      val newDF = cassandraSQLContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
      dataFrameFilterService.processBasedOnOpType(metaData, newDF)
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The invocation of `foreachRDD` does happen on the driver node. But, since we're operating at the RDD level, any transformation on it will be distributed. In your example, `rdd.map` will cause each partition to be sent to a particular worker node for computation.

Since we don't know what your `sparkStreamingService.run` method is doing, we cant tell you about the locality of its execution.

Comment: I added the code for the run method. Is this the most efficient approach? This method is parallelized right:   dataFrameFilterService.processBasedOnOpType(metaData, newDF). The way I understand it is I can avoid using collect to speed up the process so records are processed in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

The `foreachRDD` may run locally, but that just means the setup. The RDD itself is a distributed collection, so the actual work is distributed.

To comment directly on the code from the docs:

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val connection = createNewConnection()  // executed at the driver
  rdd.foreach { record =>
    connection.send(record) // executed at the worker
  }
}
```

Notice that the part of the code that is NOT based around the RDD is executed at the driver. It's the code built up using RDD that is distributed to the workers.

Your code specifically is commented below:

```
   //df.select will be distributed, but collect will pull it all back in
   var metadataDataframe = df.select("customer", "tableName", "messageContent", "initialLoadRunning").collect()
 //Since collect created a local collection then this is done on the driver
 metadataDataframe.foreach(rowD => {
      metaData = populateMetaDataService.populateSiteMetaData(rowD)
      val headers = (rowD.getString(2).split(recordDelimiter)(0))

      val fields = headers.split("\u0001").map(
        fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
      val schema = StructType(fields)

      val listOfRawData = rowD.getString(2).indexOf(recordDelimiter)
      val dataWithoutHeaders = rowD.getString(2).substring(listOfRawData + 1)

      //This will run locally, creating a distributed record
      val rawData = sparkContext.parallelize(dataWithoutHeaders.split(recordDelimiter))
//      val rawData = dataWithoutHeaders.split(recordDelimiter)
      //This will redistribute the work
      val rowRDD = rawData
        .map(_.split("\u0001"))
        .map(attributes => Row(attributes: _*))
      //again, setting this up locally, to be run distributed
      val newDF = cassandraSQLContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
      dataFrameFilterService.processBasedOnOpType(metaData, newDF)
    })
```

Ultimately, you probably can rewrite this to not need the collect and keep it all distributed, but that is for you not StackOverflow

Comment: but over here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html, if you scroll down to where they use forEachRdd, they have a comment saying that a particular piece of statement is being executed at the driver

Comment: @Ahmed I edited it to address that directly with more explicitness added than the docs

Comment: Yes so that is my question, regarding that collect. As of now, since I am doing collect, the records are processed sequentially and each of these records is then distributed amongst the executors? And then removing the collect, would all all the records to be processed in parallel rather than sequential, is that right?

Comment: One more question Justin, so this is basically a dataframe within a dataframe that I am doing here. Is the 2nd dataframe distributed as well amongst the executors? I understand the first dataframe is partitioned amongst the executors and then from those partitions of the dataframe, I am creating another dataframe, would only the executors that create the inner dataframe have that dataframe or would that be partitioned as well.